# How to calculate the "amountOutMin/amountInMax" in swapExactETHForTokens(...)?

Tags: web3js, javascript, uniswap, decentralized-exchange

In Uniswap the function `router02#swapExactETHForTokens(...)` and other similar ones which do a swap, require a parameter for "mininum amount out".

```
function swapExactETHForTokens(
  uint amountOutMin,
  //.........
```

How is it **usually** calculated?

---

The same question goes in regards to the similar parameter - `amountInMax` which is used, for instance in

```
function swapTokensForExactETH(
   uint amountOut, 
   uint amountInMax,  // !
   //.....
```

Answer (score 1):

When calling the router contract to issue a swapExactEthForTokens swap, due to the fluctuation of the market, the router takes a parameter called **AmountOutMin** which is how much token you want at least from this transaction , so you could still get more tokens than the AmountOutMin tokens initially set , its just you cant receive less tokens than the amountOutMin specified or the contract will fail.

Same goes for amountInMax vice-versa.

You can get these arguments by calling getAmountsIn and getAmountsOut function for a given swap-token pair. These functions are given in uniswap, pancakeswap router as well.

Comment: My question -- "how to calculate them in web3.js in order to pass values calculated by them futher into a swap function"?

Comment: `getAmountsIn(..)` and `getAmountsOut(...)` - how precisely would I call them? Can you give an example? I've not found any meaningful one.

Comment: Okay, for this you need pancakeswap's router address. 
Following code example in vanilla js using web.js: - 

`window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
await ethereum.enable();
const routerContract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi, routerAddress);

async function getAmountsOut(){
     let result = await routerContract.methods.getAmountsOut(amountIn, path[]).call();
     return result;
}`